# Navigate my post from single.php to a custom template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some posts on my website which are through single.php, Now I have a new page.which has some posts for which I want to use a custom template but my posts are single.php template. Can anyone help me with some code which I can write in single.php so i can navigate using post ID.??in my custom template what should i use the code for building it..?

Answer (score 1):

single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                $custom_arr = array(1,2,3,4);
                if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $custom_arr)) {
                    get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'single-custom' );
                }
                else {
                   get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'single' ); 
                }

            endwhile; else :

                get_template_part( 'parts/content', 'missing' );

            endif;
            ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then create two separate files `/parts/loop-single.php` and `/parts/loop-single-custom.php`

And instead of mapping by id, you can check by custom category or custom field on post, hard-coding ID's array its just bad practics